# ASP.NET page running on compatibility view and displays badly

Tags: asp.net, view, localhost, compatibility

I'm developing a website that displays fine in FF or Chrome, but when running on IE, it displays the message below and turn view into compatibility, thus the layout fails to display correctly and some tags and controls such asp menu disappear (still exist in html code).
Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Error Message: A problem displaying localhost caused internet explorer to refresh the page using compatibility view!

Answer (score 0):

There are most likely markup validation errors in your page that is causing IE to fall back to compatibility mode that FF or Chrome may ignore.  Ensure that your page passes validation.

Try going here [W3C Markup Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/) and running your HTML or URL through to look for any blatant errors.

The other possibility is that you are explicitly setting the meta tag for IE to force compatibility, e.g.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```

If so, remove it.